# How to view short log files on windows?

Tags: windows, logging, wireshark, syslog, snort

How to view the short log files in windows cmd prompt if possible ?

On linux sudo snort -r snort.logxxxx can be use to view the logs on the terminal .
Is there any way on windows to view similarly?
I tried -r on cmd but does not work also used notepad++ to view but I am not seeing the logs just random characters